# How to convert this JS class to Angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, oop

I need help to convert the following JavaScript class below to Angular component:

```
class Maze {
    
    constructor(size, rows, columns) {
    
        this.size = size;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.grid = [];
        this.stack = [];
    }

    setup() {
        for(let r = 0;r < this.rows; r++) {
            let row = [];
            for(let c = 0; c < this.columns; c++) {
                let cell = new Cell(r, c, this.grid, this.size);
                row.push(cell);
            }
            this.grid.push(row)
        }
    }

}
```

My attempt below, but I get the following Error:
**"core.mjs:7640 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Number -> Number -> Number]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for Number!"** :

```
export class MazeComponent implements OnInit {

  current;
  public size: Number;
  public rows: Number;
  public columns: Number;
  public grid: Cell[][];
  public stack: Number;


  constructor(size: Number, rows: Number, columns: Number) {
    this.size = 500;
    this.rows = 10;
    this.columns = 10;
    this.grid = [];
    this.stack = 0;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  setup() {
    for(let r = 0; r < this.rows; r++) {
      let row: Cell[] = [];
      for(let c = 0; c < this.columns; c++) {
        let cell: Cell = new Cell(r, c, this.grid, this.size);
        row.push(cell);
      }
      this.grid.push(row);
    }
    this.current = this.grid[0][0];
  }



}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: The parameters for the constructor (for Angular component) is for the dependency injection (service) purpose. I don't see why you need these `size: Number, rows: Number, columns: Number` in the constructor. And I don't see any reason why you need convert the class to the Component.

Comment: @YongShun I thought that vanilla JS class = Angular component

Comment: I try to convert this code to Angular version: github.com/conorbailey90/Javascript-DFS-Maze/blob/master/maze.js
There are classes, which, as I thought, need to be converted to separate components meaning Maze class requires MazeComponent,  and Cell class requires CellComponent. After I created those components I wanted to convert the  code from those classes to components :)

Comment: this might be dumb, but is your component preppended with `@Component`?

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli Yes. paste.ofcode.org/V3E9gi8KaivDtRWDcC7Rtd

Answer (score 0):

```
  current;
  @Input() size: Number;
  @Input() rows: Number;
  @Input() columns: Number;
  public grid = [];
  public stack = 0;
 

constructor() {
  }
```

in your html file where you want use this component:

```
<component-name size=500 rows=10 columns=10></component-name>
```

UPDATE:

if you want to use in a class you have to do this:

```
export class Cell {
row: number;
  column: number;
  grid: any;
  size: number;

  constructor(rows: number, columns: number, grid, size: number) {
    this.size = size;
    this.row = rows;
    this.column = columns;
    this.grid = [];
  }
}

export class Maze {
  current;
  public size: number;
  public rows: number;
  public columns: number;
  public grid: Cell[][];
  public stack: number;

  constructor(size: number, rows: number, columns: number) {
    this.size = size;
    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.grid = [];
    this.stack = 0;
  }

  setup() {
    for (let r = 0; r < this.rows; r++) {
      let row: Cell[] = [];
      for (let c = 0; c < this.columns; c++) {
        let cell: Cell = new Cell(r, c, this.grid, this.size);
        row.push(cell);
      }
      this.grid.push(row);
    }
    this.current = this.grid[0][0];
  }
}
```

and use this class like this:

```
const maze = new Maze(500, 10, 10);
console.log(maze.size); //500
console.log(maze.rows); //10
console.log(maze.columns); //10
```

https://angular-ivy-xldemp.stackblitz.io

Comment: What about creating separate maze.model.js with the code like so: paste.ofcode.org/37NL3jSFr8DFnuxxzgRmLva

Comment: But the question remains -> why can't I add (size: number, rows: number, columns: number) inside the constructor of MazeComponent, and also add the method setup() inside MazeComponent? Why can't I convert the class Maze intro Angular's MazeComponent ?

Comment: because the component constructor in angular is only for dependency injection. and using numbers in constructor cause component treat them like a service and throw a  NullInjectorError